# Url Route Order in ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have four get methods in the `employeedetails` controller as follows

1)Employees()

2)Details(id)

3)TeamInfo(id)

4)DetailsForTeam(id) and controller is:

I want url as such

1)api/Employees instead of url/employeedetails/Employee
subsequently for all

2) api/Details/id

3)api/TeamInfo/id

4)api/DetailsForTeam/id

this is my `RouteConfig.cs` configuration

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
           routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

         routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Employees",
               url: "api/employeedetails/Employees",
               defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "Employees" }
            );
             routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetEmployeeDetailsById",
            url: "api/employeedetails/Details/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetTeamMember",
            url: "api/employeedetails/TeamInfo/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "TeamInfo", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

           routes.MapRoute(
            name: "GetTeamMemberById",
            url: "api/employeedetails/DetailsForTeam/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "EmployeeDetails", action = "DetailsForTeam",id = UrlParameter.Optional}
        ); 
        }
    }
```

And this is my WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

What should i change?

Comment: Move the `Default` route to the end (the order matters). Then change the routes to `url: "api/Employees",` etc

Comment: I agree with @StephenMuecke, you should have the specific ones at the top and the generic ones at the bottom.

Comment: still getting error "No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:60669/api/Employees"

Comment: @Mahek, Do you have an `EmployeesController`?

Comment: @Mahek i think you are mixing up your mvc routes and web api routes. The first snippet you show is for configuring your mvc routes and the second is for web api.

Comment: there is only one controller i.e EmployeeDetails

Comment: @Mahek - only one controller???? Dont you have an api controller?

Comment: I mean custom controller is only one

Comment: I think I got it. I think the EmployeeDetailsController is your api controller. But as @Nkosi said, the route changes you made seems to be in mvc config- was that a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to go for attribute routing. In your web api config, add:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

And in your Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class EmployeeDetailsController
```

And your actions as:

```
[HttpGet] // if you are calling via GET verb
[Route("Employees")]
public IHttpActionResult Employees()
{
}

[HttpGet] // if you are calling via GET verb
[Route("Details/{id}"]
public IHttpActionResult Details(int id)
{
}

[HttpGet] // if you are calling via GET verb
[Route("TeamInfo/{id}"]
public IHttpActionResult TeamInfo(int id)
{
}

[HttpGet] // if you are calling via GET verb
[Route("DetailsForTeam/{id}"]
public IHttpActionResult DetailsForTeam(int id)
{
}
```